# Kendo treeview drag and drop always last position of parent

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am facing a problem in kendo treeview. I have a tree with 'folders'. I enabled the drag and drop functionality but whenever i drop a folder into another folder, it is positioned as the last item of that folder where it was dropped.

My datasource is of type kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource and the incoming data is sorted by the 'caption'/text alphabetically. I want the dropped node to be sorted alfabetically as well, so in some way i want to trigger a resort call to the node where the other node was dropped.

How would i achieve this?

I already tried defining the sort parameter in the kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource object but this doesn't change much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, a HierarchicalDataSource is a DataSource that has an array of children (items) that are also DataSources. Often, the items are just treated like a normal field, and operations on the main DataSource are not done recursively on the children.

Sorting is an example of this. As you see on https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/navigation/treeview/how-to/binding/sort-child-nodes, you need to sort the children recursively yourself:

```
    function setSort(items){
      for(var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
        if(items[i].hasChildren){
          items[i].children.sort({field: "FullName", dir: "desc"});
          setSort(items[i].children.view());
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried your example and it was even more than i needed. In my result callback after calling the 'move node' endpoint, i added target.children.sort({ field: "text", dir: "asc" }); where target is the dataItem of my dropTarget and tadaa, it worked. Thank you !